# How to return output?

Tags: c++, string, output

I need my print functions to both print and return my output. I tried doing that by concatenating output to an empty string, but I keep getting errors.

```
string ShoppingCart::PrintTotal() {
    string total = "";
    int size = cartItems.size();
    if (size == 0) {
        total += "SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY\n";
    }
    else {
        total += "OUTPUT SHOPPING CART\n";
        total += customerName + "'s Shoppig Cart - " + currentDate + "\n";
        total += "Number of Items: " + GetNumItemsInCart() + "\n";
        total += "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            total += cartItems.at(i).PrintBookCost() + "\n";
        }
    }
    cout << total;
    return total;
}
```

Comment: " I keep getting errors" what errors? Please post the error messages. And create a [mre]

Comment: `string total = "";` can be `string total;` The constructor for `std::string` does the initialization for you already.

Comment: `cartItems.at(i).PrintBookCost()` What is a `cartItems`? Does `PrintBookCost()` return a `std::string`? or is it `void PrintBookCost()`?

Comment: Save a repeated bounds check from `at` and just iterate directly: `for (const auto& item : cartItems) { total += item.PrintBookCost(); total += '\n'; }`